# Brut exception in recompiling android application

Tags: android

I wanna recompile my app through apktool v5.1 via samsung galaxy grand2. when I try to recompile and build an application, brut exception occurs. How to resolve that?

Comment: please mention what exception you are getting in the question

Comment: S: WARNING: Could not write to $HOME (/data/data/per.pqy.apktool/apktool/?), using /data/data/per.pqy.apktool instead...
S: Please be aware this is a volatile directory and frameworks could go missing, please utilize --frame-path if the default storage directory is unavailable
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [/data/data/per.pqy.apktool/apktool/openjdk/bin/aapt4.4, p, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 19, --version-code, 19, --version-name, 4.4.2-G7102XWUBNH1, -F, /data/dat

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stacktrace, you are trying to execute apktool via an Android host (in this case a Samsung Galaxy Grand2). This simply isn't possible and I'm surprised it even ran. There are multiple incompatibilities preventing apktool from running on Android host devices.

Not to mention, the stacktrace is actually telling you what the problem is. Apktool cannot write to `$HOME`. So use parameter `--frame-path` to specify an alternative path for apktool to write framework files to. Though, remember if you fix this error another will obviously occur because Apktool does not work on Android hosts.

Comment: I m using Indonesian firmware and in this firmware apktool working...... in all android samsung phone like j1 j5 j7 grand 2

Comment: And in Indonesia all are using apktool in android phone they use smoothly why I can't any solution of this error

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: Sorry for late reply sir but it's sloved now I'm also using apktool on android tnx for reply